# Webpack dynamic require causes endless compilations

Tags: webpack

I have a simple webpack plugin that writes to stdout when a compilation starts and then when it's done. When I have a dynamic `require` and run webpack in watch mode it turns out that webpack is constantly trying to compile in some kind of endless loop. All I see is:

> [07:36:42] Webpack [admin] starts compilation...
>
> [07:36:43] Webpack [admin] finished compilation.
>
> [07:36:43] Webpack [admin] starts compilation...
>
> [07:36:44] Webpack [admin] finished compilation.
>
> [07:36:44] Webpack [admin] starts compilation...
>
> [07:36:45] Webpack [admin] finished compilation.
>
> [07:36:45] Webpack [admin] starts compilation...
>
> [07:36:45] Webpack [admin] finished compilation.
>
> [07:36:46] Webpack [admin] starts compilation...
>
> [07:36:46] Webpack [admin] finished compilation.

Without any being emitted. Shouldn't it watch for file changes under specific directories and compile **only if** something changed?

Is there any way to avoid this?

**EDIT**

It actually only happens when I also include styles in my bundles and use `ExtractTextPlugin` to extract those into a css file.

This is the setup for styles:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", `css-loader!postcss-loader`, {
               publicPath: '../'
            })
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(`./${bundleFolder}/[name].css`)
]
```

**EDIT 2**

I submitted an issue to webpack's github: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2320

Comment: Yes - don't watch your output directory for changes

Comment: You mean ensure (by ContextReplacementPlugin e.g.) that the output directory is not matched by the regex?

Comment: It is not. I use require.context(... to select proper context.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue should be the same as [webpack/watchpack#25](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/25)

try this https://github.com/yessky/webpack-mild-compile, it would help.